# vue: transforms a prop in its definition

Tags: vuejs2

I've a component which is a button with some stuff like a icon. I use it like this:

```
<ti-btn icon="..." @click.native="..."></ti-btn>
```

also, I can pass a *prop* which isn't required, this *prop* is the **size**, which is a Number.

```
<ti-btn icon="..." size="32" @click.native="..."></ti-btn>
```

Now, in my component's definition, at first, I wrote:

```
<template>
   <i :class="icon" :style="{fontSize}"></i>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['icon', 'size'],
    computed: {
       fontSize() {
           return this.size ? `${this.size}px` : DEFAULT_SIZE;
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

If the size is not passed down, I set the default value. That's works, but according to good practices and vue style guide, Prop definitions should be as detailed as possible. So, I started to use this way:

```
props: {
    icon: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate(value){
            //some kind of validation here
            return value.includes('ti')
        }
    },
    size: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        default: DEFAULT_SIZE
    }
}
```

**size** prop receive a *Number*, but, it must return a string, in fact **DEFAULT_SIZE** is set to "24px" which is a *String*, also, the value receive is transformed to *value+"px"*. So, My question is, how can I transform the size prop in its own definition object, without use the computed property?

Comment: I don't think you can: **props only serve as an interface to dictate what arguments/parameters can be passed in**, and what is the accepted type/form of it. It does not serve to transform incoming data. You will have to rely on string interpolation, either as a computed prop or within the template itself. I would say that you should set the `DEFAULT_SIZE` as a Number of the sake of consistency, and compute/interpolate the actual pixel-size.

Comment: The computed property is the correct approach here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Terry mentioned in the comments, it's not possible to provide a way to transform the value of a `prop` being passed to a component from within the prop's definition itself.

You could let `size` just be a `Number`, and then add the `'px'` when you bind it to the `style`:

```
<i :class="icon" :style="{ fontSize: `${size}px` }"></i>
```

This would mean you'd need to make `DEFAULT_SIZE` equal to `24`.

---

If you're unable to change the value of `DEFAULT_SIZE`. Then your example of the `fontSize` computed property is the correct way to handle the issue.